# Getting an error on Ubuntu 21.04 after recent upgrade when running gdalinfo

Tags: ubuntu-21.04

~ $ gdalinfo --version
gdalinfo: symbol lookup error: /lib/libgdal.so.28: undefined symbol: proj_crs_get_datum_ensemble

Recently upgraded to Ubuntu 21.04 and things stopped working, tried removing all gdal, qgis installation and reinstall again and this is the latest. Previous error was https://gist.github.com/adoug/f551c96ae49bcf0dd4905cfb3ed1c910. Installing qgis from gui also comes up with an error `Unable to install QGIS Desktop: Error while installing package: installed qgis-providers package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127`

```
~ $ pip3 install gdal
Requirement already satisfied: gdal in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (3.2.2)
~ $ pip3 uninstall gdal
Found existing installation: GDAL 3.2.2
Not uninstalling gdal at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'GDAL'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

The whole install seems to be broken, is there a way to clean all and resinstall or somehow recover from this?

Answer (score 0):

Not really for a fix for current issue, but used fresh anaconda install as a workaround to get gdal working again

```
conda update --all
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```